# Regex to merge multiple numbers with spaces in one line

Tags: java, regex

I need a Regex to merge multiple numbers in a line without merging them all together.

Example line :

```
Hello World9.99 123 456.00 7 890 123.45 0.97
```

My desired output is :

```
Hello World9.99 123456.00 7890123.45 0.97
```

I know basic regex but am not experienced with lookaheads/behinds.

So far I created this method :

```
final String regex = "(?<!\\.\\d{1,3})\\s+(?=\\d{1,3}\\.?\\d{2}?)";

public String mergeNumbers(String s){
    return s.replaceAll(regex, "");
}
```

This works fine if the number tied to the word has a dot.

But I just can't figure out how to match this line without a dot at the beginning :

```
Hello World99 123 456.00 7 890 123.45 0.97
```

This is returning :

```
Hello World99123456.00 7890123.45 0.97
```

but I want :

```
Hello World99 123456.00 7890123.45 0.97
```

So my question is :

How can I modify my regex to match both cases?

Comment: It's a bad idea to use regex for these purposes

Comment: How do you know which spaces you want to remove (or which numbers merge)? Try to describe this rule.

Comment: Try [`"\\b(?<!\\.)(\\d+)\\s+(?=\\d)"`](https://regex101.com/r/ciRf47/2) to replace with `"$1"`.

Comment: I'm with Pshemo: what would the rules for those merges be? What are you trying to achieve in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using

```
.replaceAll("\\b(?<!\\.)(\\d+)\\s+(?=\\d)", "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ciRf47/2).

**Details**:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\.)` -  there can be no `.` immediately before the current location
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` backreference from the string replacement pattern): one or more digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?=\\d)` - there must be a digit immediately to the right of the current location.